# console says I have error what is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working fine however when I check in the console on google chrome I get an error. Out of curiosity I really like to know what it means as the code seems to be working fine.

heres my code:

```
var images = [];
var imageIndex = 0;
var $mainImage = $(".thumb-large img");
var $mainCaption = $(".thumb-large p");
var $thumbnails = $(".thumbnails img");
//var $mainName = $(".thumb-large-descrip p.name")



function showImage(index) {
  $mainImage.attr({src: images[index].source});// this is where the error is showing
  $mainCaption.text(images[index].caption);
  $mainImage.attr({name: images[index].artistName});
}
```

I gave a snippet of my code to where it says the error. Below is exactly what google chrome console says :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined

just looking on advice on what that means??? let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It means that `images[index]` is undefined.

Comment: your `images` array seems empty `images[0]` would return undefined.

Comment: It means that `images[index]` is undefined. Most likely whatever index you're passing into the function doesn't exist in the `images` array.

Comment: what this could typically mean is that you call `showImage` before your image array is populated. If the error does not prevent your code from behaving properly, it is probably because there is another call to that function, made after the array is filled

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, as soon as I read them I saw what was wrong. I just need to load the array earlier .so I know for future why have I got a -1 before my question, what was so wrong with my question???

Comment: @troybeckett I didn't down-vote, but this is a very common error, searching it would've given you more than plenty of insight.

Comment: okay so I got it because someone felt I was being lazy. ok cool, just want to learn how the forum works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `var images = [];` does not contain any elements.

If your array was `var arr = ['a','b','c']` and you tried accessing `arr[5]`, it would return `undefined`. That is what is happening here.

Add some data to your array.

In your case, it would look like:

```
var images = [
  { source: 'http://placehold.it/350x150',
    caption: 'This thing',
    artistName: 'troy beckett'
  },
  { source: 'http://placehold.it/250x250',
    caption: 'Another thing',
    artistName: 'troy beckett'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the image at index exists before trying to access it. You could do:

```
function showImage(index) {
  if(images.length > index) { //This checks that something exists at that index and only if it exists does the following code run
    $mainImage.attr({src: images[index].source});
    $mainCaption.text(images[index].caption);
    $mainImage.attr({name: images[index].artistName});
  } else {
    console.log("Tried to access a nonexistent image at index: " + index)
  }
}
```